# Make last row NON sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm have sortable table rows in my angular project, but sorting rows also contains query-ui code elements and now i wan't to make last row NON sortable.

HTML

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <table style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ui:sortable ng:model="list">
            <tr ng:repeat="item in list" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Non Sortable</td>
                <td>Non Sortable</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>{{list}}
        <hr>
</div>
```

controller

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "thre", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

Here is working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/valor_/fc7oftkn/

So how to make last row non sortable? If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move them to the `<tfoot>` like below.

```
<table style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ui:sortable ng:model="list">
    <tr ng:repeat="item in list" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
      <td>{{$index}}</td>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>{{list}}
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Non Sortable</td>
      <td>Non Sortable</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: lol :D i'm laughing my ass off here. How didn't i figure this out xD
Thx. I will accept you answer as soon as it will be allowed

Comment: @Valor_ haha :) Thanks